# Json Encoding fails because of strange chars. Escaping with $pdo->quote($data) not working

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, escaping

I query the database, and then I want to encode in json the response.

Because of two fields, 'name' and 'description' which contain some spooky chars, the encoding of the json is not succeding.

After I encode the array received from the database, the json has only 4 chars length.

If I do not query from the databse the tables 'name' and 'description' which contain those very strange chars, everything is running. I can encode the array and then use it.

I have tried 
    $pdo->quote($data[name]) 
and 
    $pdo->quote($data[description])
, the escaping is done, but the problem is not solving.. The json is still messed up by those strange chars.

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Can you talk to the character encodings you are using (what is a "spooky" character? Are you using a common encoding in your DB columns, DB connection, and application? The `quote()` method is really unrelated to character encoding issues.

Comment: My DB columns collaction is latin1_swedish_ci. I also tried utf8_general_ci but nothing changed. I do not use anything else.

Comment: I've read that quote() is for escaping, I assumed there is some text in the description/name of my data that messes the json architecture

Comment: spooky char example 1: 'ÃŽnvaÅ£Äƒ sÄƒ

Comment: Was that a UTF-8 that got mangled by inserting into latin1 column? I guess what I am saying si that you may have an underlying issue with your character data.  If you are expecting to work with UTF-8 (which is fine for JSON). You need to make sure the whole application is set up for that.  That you DB connection uses the proper encoding, that the table and/or columns use proper encoding, that PHP reading./writing to DB uses proper encoding, etc.

Comment: Everything is fine. The array received from the database is oke. The problem is just with the json encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. 
I had to set the charset of the db connection:

```
try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo -> exec('SET NAMES utf8'); // FIX

}
catch( PDOException $excepiton ) {
echo "Connection error :" . $excepiton->getMessage();
}
?>
```